# Backdrop image displaying but no effect when nodes connect just a white x over the image

Tags: compositing-nodes

So I'm having a small issue I am trying to create an iris image for a pair of eyes I'm creating I am completely new to this (Noob) and have been following a turtorial that I have done and completed correctly on my laptop but I ran into a issue I just can not figure out I am currently trying to make some adjustments in the compositor and when I connect my blur to the render layers node and composite node there is no effect in the backdrop image but it shows when rendered, for some reason I cannot upload an image wish I could it would be a lot simpler but hey technology lol if anyone has a clue I can really use the help thanks

Comment: I do have a viewers node In place and I have the backdrop option selected everything is working fine and the back drop image appears but whenever  I make a change within the nodes the backdrop won't display a preview of the work done but it shows in the render. Sorry if I sound like a complete idiot but I am new to this and just learning as I progress so any information is greatly appreciated

Comment: Without an image of your nodes it's hard to guess what you are doing. Please do a screen capture of the compositng nodes (press Ctrl+F3 to save an image in blender) then use the edit link under your question and add the image. To understand how to add images to the question please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Comment: Also, consider using commas, periods an other forms of puctuation.

Answer (score 1):

The backdrop image won't appear until you use a Viewer node to output. You can feed the same source as the proper Composite output node, or any source to check what is happening in your setup.